# How is dynamic data implemented in the SAP Cloud Platform Portal Service?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

Pretty self-explanatory, but I'm putting together a 'freestyle' site in SCP Portal.

How do I pull in dynamic data? I can see an HTML widget but nothing else?

Comment: Isnt Portal service only a rendering engine? Like a frame around an app? I always used webide Apps and right click "convert to Portal app". Then deploy to scp, then use Portal service and add the app with a catalogue... Then it is avaialable in the same choice where you select HTML page.... Ill expect this is the right way but happy to see options!

Comment: Tried it..  found in negative cache: 'PortalTest/PortalTest/Component.js' from /sap/fiori/portaltest/webapp/Component.js: failed to load 'PortalTest/PortalTest/Component.js' from /sap/fiori/portaltest/webapp/Component.js: 404 -

Comment: delete all caches? :D